React navigation en React Native: Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Setup del proyecto
Estoy desarrollando un proyecto de React Native con React navigation y este es mi setup
React Native Version: 0.74.4
React Version: 18.2.0
React Navigation Version: ^6.1.18
package.json
A continuación mi package.json:
{
  "name": "recepify",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.14.1",
    "recepify": "file:"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.86",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.86",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.86",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.86",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}


Hice algunas modificaciones de acuerdo a la documentación y obtuve este error:
...

:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\<project>\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\<project>\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\<project>\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Script 'C:<project>\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script. > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 5s.

Información adicional
Entorno de desarrollo:

OS: Windows 11
Estoy usando node version manager (nvm)

Por ahora he intentando lo siguiente:

Verifiqué que Node.js está correctamente instalado y disponible en el PATH del sistema. La versión activa utilizada con nvm es compatible con los requisitos del proyecto.
Reinstalación de dependencias: Removido node_modules y reinstaladas todas las dependencias usando npm install.
Actualizado React Native CLI: Asegurado que @react-native-community/cli y los paquetes relacionados están actualizados.
Limpieza de caché: Borrado de cachés de Gradle usando gradlew clean y eliminado .gradle/caches.
Verificación del entorno: Ejecutamos npx react-native doctor para comprobar cualquier error de configuración en el entorno de desarrollo.


Ve a la carpeta android/ de tu proyecto, luego corre ./gradlew --stop.
Vuelve a hacer build de tu proyecto y correlo de nuevo.

Hice lo que me comentaste y me sale de hecho el mismo error. Comandos que ejecuté:

./gradlew --stop
./gradlew build

Error que obtengo:


Where:
Script 'C:\Users\juand\projects\recepify\recepify\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401


What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.



Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Puedes probar gradlew --stop? el comando que mencione en la respuesta funciona en Linux. Luego corre gradlew cleanBuildCache, siempre dentro de la carpeta de android.

Justo probé lo que me comentas y el error persiste;
Probé ./gradlew --stop y ./gradlew cleanBuildCache y el error persiste, es exactamente el mismo, qué raro
